# There seems to be no downvote rep cap

Tags: feature-request, down-votes, daily-reputation-limit

It appears to me that there is no downvote rep-cap. There are some users who during the recent events have lost a lot more than 200 rep in a single day.

How's that possible that there is no such negative limit yet?

Since downvotes cost you *only* 2 points, which makes 20% of the upvote rep-cap, how about limiting them to 40 points a day?

It is not fair that you can earn only 200 points from upvotes while at the same time lose any amount from downvotes.

Everything on SE seem to have limits, flags, votes, max rep etc... just the loss of reputation is unlimited so far. Why is that so?

Shouldn't this be balanced to protect you from losing reputation too as much as it *protects* you from earning too much of it in a short period of time?

Comment: Can you point me to any examples of users who lost more than 200 rep due only to downvotes where the Q/A wasn't deleted? They've got to be few and far between, I'd think.

Comment: "It is not fair that you can earn only 200 points from upvotes while at the same time loose any amount from downvotes." Why isn't that fair? You have to provide *some* rational, not just state that something "isn't fair".

Comment: @meagar and what is the rational behind limiting it upwards only but not downwards? Shouldn't this be balanced? There was that blog post that everything has its limits... yeah, almost everything, downvotes don't seem to be in that group.

Comment: upvotes can earn you privileges, earning privileges is more of a problem than losing them.

Comment: @JeffDarwood The upwards limits prevent people from gaining massive amounts of reputation from asking a single novel question. A downwards limit would let you vote for free after you reach the threshold. There is nothing comparable about the limits or their purposes.

Comment: I assume this question is purely based on downvote only, right? Not including the -100 rep penalty from spam/rude flag?

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. yes, the same principles should apply as with the upvotes. You can earn more than 200 but not from upvotes only. Likewise it should be limited in the opposite direction - ideally to not less than 40.

Comment: You have to write a really bad post in order to lose 200 rep in a day. You would need $((100 + 5 * $up)) down votes

Comment: Since a downvote is 20% of the weight of an upvote, I would allow the inverse ratio of downvotes as lower limit. 20 upvotes (20 * 10 rep) = 100 downvotes (100 * |-2| rep). Even if it's unlikely to get such an off-day, what's wrong with building in this counter limit to balance the upper limit?

Comment: There is, actually, one specific way to lose far more rep than gain in a day: bounties.  You can lose up to 500 rep.  Granted, *gaining* that bounty is also a way to bypass the maximum, but then, it's also immune to the rep cap, so you could, in theory, gain (and lose!) quite a bit through bounties.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose Sara Chipps' reputation dropped to 1 after posting the first attempt to an apology. She had some reputation before, IIRC.

Answer (score 9):

Why should there be a down vote rep cap?

To begin with, if your question gets a 1:1 up vote:down vote response, you're still net positive in rep. You're getting rep for participating, even if it's unclear whether or not your contribution was a good one. Unless you ask extremely bad questions, you're probably not going to be losing much rep at all.

We have reasons to limit upvote rep gain; for example, to prevent sock puppeting and rep farming. It also helps to prevent one lucky question from rocketing you up the rep ladder.

The limit/balancing to make sure you don't lose all your rep at once from one bad question is in the difference of rep gain/loss between up vs downvotes. In that sense, I'd say the system is already "balanced". You're already protected. IMO, down votes should remove MORE rep.

And if you really do ask such a bad question that you lose all your rep in one question.. well, that's kind of your own fault.

Comment: This is not what I mean. Not me loosing it but the person who is downvoted should be able to loose more than n rep per day. Also why are you saying _we have reasons_ - you don't seem to work for SE. It'd be better to say _they have reasons_.

Comment: @JeffDarwood I don't understand your comment, I think i'm addressing exactly what your comment says? "We" refers to the community (not that it exists anymore)

Comment: exactly, sock puppeting downvotes might also be a problem - why isn't this addressed yet?

Comment: @JeffDarwood It is. SE has all sorts of defenses built in to prevent, detect, reverse etc that kind of behavior.

Comment: Also worth noting that you can usually delete heavily downvoted posts. Usually because you can't delete questions with positive answers or accepted answers.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose double standards. Nothing more. You're trying to defend it but you know it too that limiting the loss of rep is the right thing to do.

Comment: @JeffDarwood I'm not trying to defend anything, I was simply suggesting something that OP could use in their answer. I think it is an thought-provoking suggestion, but I'm unsure how I feel about it. I'm definitely not  certain that it is for sure the correct thing to do.

Answer (score 4):

There is a downvote rep cap. You cannot lose more than all of your reputation minus one (reputation must be a strictly positive number).

From [whats-reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation):

> All users start with one reputation point, and reputation can never drop below 1